# need help in python multiprocessing.lock()

Tags: python, variables, multiprocessing

I'm using a Python program to compute an average value of a list of floats.
Following the program logic:

1. The program is started with some arguments.
2. A list "hostgroups" is created.
3. For-in loop over the list "hostgroups" starting a function worker(hosgroup,var1, var2,var3,...)
4. Inside the worker-function two variables are build with some input variables of the worker

   - 4a. Inside the worker a subworker-function is called with some input variables of the worker
   - 4b. The subworker returns some new variables
   - 4c. Back in the worker
   - 4d. some things are done
   - 4d. At last in the worker a final-function is called with some variables.

So far, so fine!

My next step is to set up a multiprocessing... who can help?

UPDATE:
Here is my actual approach:

```
class Consumer(multiprocessing.Process):

    def __init__(self, task_queue, result_queue):
        multiprocessing.Process.__init__(self)
        self.task_queue = task_queue
        self.result_queue = result_queue

    def run(self):
        proc_name = self.name
        while True:
            next_task = self.task_queue.get()
            if next_task is None:
                # Poison pill means shutdown
                print '%s: Exiting' % proc_name
                self.task_queue.task_done()
                break
            print '%s: %s' % (proc_name, next_task)
            answer = next_task()
            self.task_queue.task_done()
            self.result_queue.put(answer)
        return


class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, hostgroup, lock):
        self.hostgroup = hostgroup
        self.lock = lock
    def __call__(self):
        print 'Doing something fancy for %s!' % self.hostgroup
        try:
            lock.acquire()
            worker(self.hostgroup,hostsfile,mod_inputfile,outputdir,testmode,backup_dir,start_time,end_time,rrdname,unit,yesterday,now_epoch,rrd_interval,rrd_heartbeat,name)
        finally:
            lock.release()
    def __str__(self):
        return 'str %s' % self.hostgroup

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    # Establish communication queues
    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue()
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Start consumers
    num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    print 'Creating %d consumers' % num_consumers
    consumers = [ Consumer(tasks, results)
                  for i in xrange(num_consumers) ]
    for w in consumers:
        w.start()

    # Enqueue jobs
    for hostgroup in hostgroups:
        tasks.put(Task(hostgroup,lock))

    # Add a poison pill for each consumer
    for i in xrange(num_consumers):
        tasks.put(None)

    # Wait for all of the tasks to finish
    tasks.join()
```

**--->  Fine, so far! But no Lock is possible, all results are the same....
Why is lock.acquire() not working?**

Comment: You can help yourself by reading documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html#module-multiprocessing

Answer (score 3):

I find `multiprocessing.Pool` to be much easier to use than the Queue class. The basic setup is

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
p = Pool(processes=<number of processes>)
p.map(function, [a, b, c])
```

Which will call `function(a)`, `function(b)`, `function(c)` in independent processes